# Youtube video upload API from angular 8 is resulting parsing error

Tags: angular, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

trying to connect to Youtube from my angular web application to upload a video to my channel.

```
public uploadVideoToYouTube(token, obj) {
    let newHeader = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    newHeader.Authorization = newHeader.Authorization + token;
    console.log(obj);
    const httpOptions3 = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(newHeader)
    };
    let formData = new FormData();
    let snippet = {
        description: obj.snippet.description,
        title: obj.snippet.title,
        // tags: obj.snippet.tags
    };

    formData.append('snippet', JSON.stringify(snippet));
    formData.append('video', obj.snippet.video);


    return this.http.post<any>('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=' + environment.API_KEY, formData, httpOptions3)
        .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

But as i call this API am getting parsing error response.

Comment: can you post that error.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body), you shouldn't have posted your video meta data as `FormData` (ie. multipart/form-data), but instead as a [`video resource`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) JSON text, as your `Content-Type` header specifies.

Note that you're calling the wrong API endpoint, since for uploading videos you have to invoke this one:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos`.